# Meanjs user role authorization

Tags: express, oauth, meanjs

What is the easiest yet still secure way of doing role authorization in MeanJS?

For example if in the articles example I wanted to have admin users who were allowed to edit other people's articles.

Is the way this was supposed to work just changing the authentication.client.service.js to be something like

```
// Authentication service for user variables
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [
    function() {
        var _this = this;

        _this._data = {
            user: window.user,
            isAdmin: function(){
                var isAdmin = false;
                for (var userRoleIndex in this.user.roles) {
                    if ('admin' === this.user.roles[userRoleIndex]) {
                        isAdmin = true;
                    }
                }
                return isAdmin;
            }
        };

        return _this._data;
    }
]);
```

This doesn't seem very secure. Should the authentication be done in express on the server?  If so how should I do it? It looks like there is already something in users.authorization.server.controller.js but I am not sure how I am supposed to call that from the client side.

```
/**
 * User authorizations routing middleware
 */
exports.hasAuthorization = function(roles) {
    var _this = this;

    return function(req, res, next) {
        _this.requiresLogin(req, res, function() {
            if (_.intersection(req.user.roles, roles).length) {
                return next();
            } else {
                return res.status(403).send({
                    message: 'User is not authorized'
                });
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Also a small nit on terminology: *Authentication* is identify verification. *Authorization* is giving permissions.

Comment: I think that it is slightly different. I am looking how to do it on a level less than the page.  I suppose I can just stop them at the page level. The difference is probably not big enough to warrant another question.  I'll try your (@AndrewLavers) solution I think I should be able to get it to work for me. Cheers